# How deploy two different apps in ios without having them overwritten

Tags: ios, iphone, deployment

I want to have two version of the same IOS app to stay in the same time in the same device, one for testing and the other for production.

The app is built using phonegap build, so what I have done is

- using two different bundle id specified in build.xml (edit: config.xml), so that one is dk.xxxDev.mobile, and the other one is dk.xxx.mobile
- having two different apps in the apple developer page, so now I still have the previous one for dk.xxx.mobile and the new one dk.xxxDev.mobile
- building using two different provisioning file, one for each app (one is using a developer profile, while the other is using an ad hoc certificate, but i guess we don't care about it)

Still, every time I deploy using itunes or testflightapp, one app overwrites the other one! What am I doing wrong?

edit: I Also changed 
- the tag "name" in the build.xml (so that testflightapp can distinguish them )
- I'm using different filnames when I add the app to iTunes

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the 2 versions of the app generate are using the same IPA file name?

The file naming convention for the Mpbile Apps is as follows:

app_name.version.IPA file

iTunes in the Mac or in the PC store the mobile apps in IPA format and if they are using the same name, installing one will override the other.     This is a valid question for Apple Support and this is something that a future version of iTunes may fix.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something different from what I wrote, I was probably using the same certificate for both versions.

So doing exactly what I wrote, it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change bundle identifier of one of the apps

Select Project in Xcode, then select target and in general tab you will see bundle identifier string.

e.g. com.YourCompane.AppName change "AppName"

Comment: I did that through the config.xml, since I'm using phonegap build (not just phonegap), so I don't even use xcode.